# Disposição de boxes em grid

Tags: css3

Estou com dificuldades para formatar o seguinte grid, quando tenho vários boxes, o formato fica correto.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Quando apenas um box é adicionado/mostrado, o grid pega 100% da minha div pai, e gostaria que fosse `155px`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<div class="grid">

<?php for ($i = 0; $i < 15; $i++) :?>
    <a href=""><div class="mbp">
        box grid            
    </div></a>
<?php endfor;?>

</div>

.grid {
  display: grid;
  width: 900px;
}

.grid { 
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, 
  minmax(155px, 1fr));
  grid-gap: 10px 10px;
}

.grid a > div {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
  height: 290px;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cara pelo que entendi que vc quer fazer basicamente vc está trocando o `auto-fit` pelo `auto-fill`. o `auto-fit` a célula do `Grid` cresce até ocupar toda a largura do *contaier* caso não haja mais filhos. Com `auto-fill` a célula do `Grid` não cresce, mesmo que só tenha um filho.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Segue o código da imagem acima.

```css
html,
body {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}

.grid {
 display: grid;
 width: 900px;
}

.grid {
 grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill,
   minmax(155px, 1fr));
 grid-gap: 10px 10px;
}

.grid a>div {
 display: flex;
 flex-flow: column;
 height: 290px;
 border: 1px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
 <a href="">
  <div class="mbp">
   box grid
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="">
  <div class="mbp">
   box grid
  </div>
 </a>
 <a href="">
  <div class="mbp">
   box grid
  </div>
 </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Tenta usar o teu css dessa forma, segue o link da [documentação](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) do Flexbox.

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 155px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
  <li class="flex-item">2</li>
  <li class="flex-item">3</li>
  <li class="flex-item">4</li>
  <li class="flex-item">5</li>
  <li class="flex-item">6</li>
  <li class="flex-item">7</li>
</ul>
```

```css
.flex-container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.flex-item {
  background: black;
  padding: 5px;
  width: 155px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 3em;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<ul class="flex-container">
  <li class="flex-item">1</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: quase isso velho, unico problema é quando só tem uma `flex-item` ela fica no centro, tem q ficar na esquerda

Comment: @goio, no css `flex-container`, altere o `justify-content` para `left`